# How to Add AD Groups in SharePoint Site?

Tags: permissions, active-directory

I have created AD Groups but sharepoint picker throws the following error No exact "match was found" even though the groups exists in AD?

I added these groups to folders on both servers(AD and SP Server) to ensure that these AD groups are correctly added.

How do I resolve and what is causing this malfunction? 
I have noticed that the UPS isn't created is this maybe the reason?

Comment: you need only type your domain/group.
vasalam

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Active directory groups should be of type "Security Group" to be added to SP.

Comment: This is the correct answer. I was trying to add an AD group that was failing with the same message. Turned out to be a distribution list. I was able to a security group though.

Comment: This topic is exactly what I am struggling with since few days! Indeed, I have a Security Group in AD which I added to sharepoint group. The workflow works BUT does not send the approval request to the users who are member of that sec. group.  Maybe, it needs to be a distribution type instead?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to create separate SP Group if you have already created AD Group. All you need to do is add that AD Group as how you add a normal user.

For e.g. If you got a AD group called DOMAIN\Marketing-SharePoint, all you need to do is add that add that add group by going to Site Actions > site permission > grant permission and add that group.

Comment: Is it possible to get the users from AD Group?

Comment: You can't see the individual members of an AD group within SharePoint. If the AD group is a member of a SP group, checking permissions for an individual will list SP groups that they belong to even if only through an AD group. I recommend always placing AD groups within SP groups to grant permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Authentication provider should be Windows Ntlm . AD groups should be part of your domain. Then adding groups is like adding normal users. It should resolve itself